# How to fix NextAuth With Prisma for mysql specified key is too long - error

Tags: mysql, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am willing to use NextAuth with Prisma Adaptor wiht Mysql (5.7.36) database, but i am getting the following error.

```
Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
   0: sql_migration_connector::apply_migration::migration_step
           with step=CreateTable { table_id: TableId(0) }
             at migration-engine\connectors\sql-migration-connector\src\apply_migration.rs:21
   1: sql_migration_connector::apply_migration::apply_migration
             at migration-engine\connectors\sql-migration-connector\src\apply_migration.rs:10
   2: migration_core::state::SchemaPush
             at migration-engine\core\src\state.rs:381
```

Without nextauth I am ubale to do basic CRUD operation without any issue.

as per the documentation (https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma) i have followed all the steps like.

1. Created data base ith name `prisma_mysql`
2. Added Database urs in .env file. database url is (password is empty)

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@localhost:3306/prisma_mysql?schema=public"
```

3. installed the required dependencies
   npm install next-auth @prisma/client @next-auth/prisma-adapter
   npm install prisma --save-dev
4. now here is the shcema i am trying to create the tables but getting the key too long error.

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                 String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId             String
  type               String
  provider           String
  providerAccountId  String
  refresh_token      String?  @db.Text
  access_token       String?  @db.Text
  expires_at         Int?
  token_type         String?
  scope              String?
  id_token           String?  @db.Text
  session_state      String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

i want to use mysql, please let me know the fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visited phpmyadmin > Clicked on SQL pasted

```
SET GLOBAL default_storage_engine = 'InnoDB';
```

worked for me.

Comment: To set GLOBAL you must have database privileges that are not always present. This only work in a few cases, and is not a solution, is a workaround.